# Executing php script on button click and returning value by ob_start

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have button which in enclosed by `<a>` tag. When clicked, it executes `redirect.php` script.

login.php - contains

```
 <a href="./redirect.php"><input type = "button" id = "loginButton2" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Login | Twitter " style = "left:650px; margin-top: -32px; position:relative"/> </a>
```

`redirect.php` contains twitter authentication code. If authenticated successfully then gives `id` and `name`. I want to fetch these both value in index.php

Using `ob_start();` I can receive values from php script to JS function via json.

But I am confused about how to manage the code in `index.php` to execute script on button click and receiving these two value also.

redirect.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
    require_once('config.php');

    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
        header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
    }
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
    $twitteruser = $content->{'screen_name'};
    $notweets = 5;
    $tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

    $id = $content->{'id'}; 
    $name = $content->{'name'}; 

?>
```

Please let me know if you need further explaination.

Bottomline:

1. Rather executing `redirect.php` script on `link click`, I want it to execute via function on button click event.
2. Getting `id` and `name` from redirect.php to index.php after `redirect` script executed

I already have session_start() to manage the twitter session. So dont want to mess up using mutiple session if not necessary ..

UPDATE after david's answer

```
<body>
        <input type="button" value="Run somePHPfile.php" id = "b1" />
<script>    
$('#b1').click(function () {
    window.location.href = 'redirect.php';    

$.get('index.php', function(data) { //If I put this out side click then it gives undefined value for name and id before redirect.php gets executed
    // data.id is the id
        var id= data.id;
        var name = data.name;
        alert(name);
        });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Apologize to say:

On button click `redirect.php` script executed. `redirect.php` includes other files, which finally reach to index.php. And `index.php`  returns `name` and `id`.

So is this enough to manage it : `$.get('index.php', function(data) { ... }`

Comment: It's not clear what `ob_start` has to do with anything, or what functionality you're trying to achieve on `index.php`.  Your code sends the user to `redirect.php` already, doesn't it?  Isn't that the intended effect?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @David: please see I added bottom line.

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh: yes, ajax is solution but I need to behave with code that I could not figure out ..

Comment: save both the values in session and redirect to index.php and get session variable there

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh: That's kind of an unnecessary use of server-side state and an unnecessary reload of the page after an AJAX call, don't you think?  Why not just return the values to the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind to a click event of an HTML button, you would use JavaScript.  Since you tagged the question with jQuery, I'll assume its use.  The event handler would look something like this:

```
$('#loginButton2').click(function () {
    window.location.href = 'redirect.php';
});
```

Note: This simulates an anchor click effectively.  If you instead want to more closely resemble an HTTP redirect, you might want to use this instead:

```
window.location.replace('redirect.php');
```

As for the `id` and `name` values, how exactly does this flow return the user *to* `index.php` in the first place?  Your `redirect.php` has, well, a redirect (though not all code paths result in that) so it kind of assumes non-AJAX interaction.  (I think XHR follows redirects sometimes, but the behavior is different from one browser to another.)

If the redirect isn't terribly important and you just want to make an AJAX call to `redirect.php`, then you can do that with a simple AJAX request:

```
$.get('redirect.php');
```

In order to get those values back to the page, they'll need to be emitted from `redirect.php`.  Something like this:

```
echo json_encode((object) array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name));
```

Then in the client-side code you would have those values available in the AJAX callback:

```
$.get('redirect.php', function(data) {
    // data.id is the id
    // data.name is the name

    // use these values client-side however you need
});
```

Comment: @Programming_crazy: It's not clear to me what you're attempting in the updated code.  If you're using an AJAX request, you shouldn't need the `window.location.href=` line anymore.  Additionally, why are you issuing an AJAX request to `index.php` and not `redirect.php`?  I thought that was the target here.

Comment: Yes, it was the target. and your answer is correct as per my original question. But later I found that on button click `redirect.php` script executes. Which in turn call `index.php`, and `name` & `id` are comming from `index.php`

Comment: please see : https://github.com/karimkhanp/twitteroauth/blob/master/index.php &  https://github.com/karimkhanp/twitteroauth/blob/master/redirect.php

Comment: I selected your answer as correct. I appreciate if you take this to reach success. Can issue new thread if you wish ..

Comment: @Programming_crazy: Sorry, but it's still not clear to me *what* the new issue even is.  It sounded like you wanted to make an AJAX request to another page, which would invoke some server-side code, and then get a result from that request to use on the current page.  The files you've linked to look very different.  Functionality which the question says was on `redirect.php` appears instead on `index.php`, and I see no HTML or JavaScript at all.  It's very unclear what the intended functionality is here or where it's not working.

Comment: Yes, I wanted as what you understood with `It sounded like you wanted to make an AJAX request to another page, which would invoke some server-side code, and then get a result from that request to use on the current page.`. Let me try to show you demo page

Comment: I am making ajax request from login.php to execute `redirect.php`. Which would invoke some other file let's say index.php. this `index.php` having `id` and `name`. So can I get them in `login.php`?

Comment: @Programming_crazy: It depends on how it "invokes" that other file or what other involved components are doing.  From the perspective of client-side code, it's just issuing a request to the server and receiving a response.  How the server-side code calculates that response is unknown to (and irrelevant to) the client.  `redirect.php` can include functionality on `index.php` to calculate the value and return it.  Whether or not it *should* is another matter entirely.  I suspect you're over-complicating this design a bit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46370/discussion-between-programming-crazy-and-david)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    $("#loginButton2").on('click',function(){
    window.location.href="redirect.php";
    });
    </script>
```

and in redirect.php file

```
    $_SESSION['id']=$id ;
    $_SESSION['name']=$name;
```

and also

```
<a href="./redirect.php"><input type = "button" id = "loginButton2" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Login | Twitter " style = "left:650px; margin-top: -32px; position:relative"/> </a>
```

to

```
    <input type = "button" id = "loginButton2" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Login | Twitter " style = "left:650px; margin-top: -32px; position:relative"/>
```

Comment: Yes, Why down vote?? please explain reason who did. It may help both karthick and me

Comment: He needs the values calculated by `redirect.php` server-side to be available to `index.php` after the calculation.  How does this accomplish that?  This just sends the user to `redirect.php` and then keeps the values server-side.  The `a` link already did that by itself, without the need for JavaScript code.  The use of session state isn't really necessary when all he needs to do is make a request to the server and get two small values as a response in the background, and the additional page loads will degrade overall performance and user experience.

Comment: @David he want that values to access in index.php, so better to handle   values using seesion variables, also we what this to be done on the button click event instead of hyperlink

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh: No, it's not better to handle this with session variables.  A request to the server can return a response, there's no need to juggle state on the server-side.  This use of session state is just putting values in a more global scope when they only need to be returned from a local scope.  Global scope is not a dumping ground for variables whenever the developer doesn't know how to manage them.  And state-tracking is unnecessary in an HTTP environment when all that's needed is to fetch a response from the server.